# Swift как поймать окончание звукового файла?

Tags: swift, события, аудио

есть кнопка для проигрывания звукового файла. По умолчанию кнопка с картинкой условно говоря "Play". После нажатия эта картинка меняется на знак проигрывания файла или как это обычно делается на "Пауза" (две вертикальные полоски). Т.е. пользователь видит, что в данный момент звуковой файл проигрывается и может остановить это воспроизведение. Тогда картинка "Play" возвращается на кнопку.

Но как поймать окончание звукового файла, чтобы автоматически вернуть на кнопку знак "Play"? Т.е. без участия пользователя. Другими словами, как поймать событие окончания звукового файла, чтобы к нему привязать смену картинки?

---

Увы, не работает.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self,
                                            selector: #selector(playerDidPlayToEndTime),
                                            name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                            object: nil
       )
    }

    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Something", ofType: "mp3")!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        
        do {
             audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
             audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
           // couldn't load file :(
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }

    @objc private func playerDidPlayToEndTime() {
        // Делаете здесь все что нужно после окончания проигрывания
        print("The music is finished")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если используете просто `AVPlayer`:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidPlayToEndTime), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
...
@objc private func playerDidPlayToEndTime() {
    // Делаете здесь все что нужно после окончания проигрывания
}
```